# Python function not loading in node.js

Tags: python, node.js, express, spawn

I'm trying to run a python function with arguments from node.js.

When I run `process.stdout.on` nothing happens. Here's the full code:

**Node.js**

```
app,get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const spawn = require('child_process').spawn; // Should this be called every time, or can I just put it with my other `require` statements?
    var process = await spawn('python', [
        '../../python/hello.py',
        'Hello',
        'World'
    ]);
    process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
        // res.send(data.toString()); // When I do this, the website never loads
    });
    res.send('test');
});
```

**Python**

```
import sys

print("Output from Python")
print("First name: " + sys.argv[1])
print("Last name: " + sys.argv[2])
```

I'm running the node app via `nodemon`, and I'm not seeing any results. (I'm new to python, so I don't know if anything has to be running while the node app is running.

It doesn't seem like the python file is loading. How can I get it to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you're using `await` for `spawn`- I ran the following similar code and had output printed to the console:

app.js

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const process = spawn('python', ['./script.py', 'Hello', 'World']);
process.stdout.on('data', (data) => console.log(data.toString()));
```

script.py

```
import sys
print("Python")
print("First: " + sys.argv[1])
print("last: " + sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: Do I need to install anything?

Comment: Actually, when I run it in app.js, it works. But when it's in a `app,get('/', ` it doesn't work

Comment: Did you hit the endpoint on your local host or make any other get request to the base?  You'll need to actually make a request to the server if you want to bind it to a `get` endpoint

Comment: Yes. The issue was having `async` in the function. That's it. Thanks. Does `require('child_process').spawn` have to get called every time, or can I put it above the file?

Comment: Should be fine at the top of the file :)